# Problems in computer vision that use optimization method in graph theory?

Tags: computer-vision, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization

I am supposed to give a presentation on optimization algorithms on graphs. On the other hand, I am also very interested in computer vision. And I hope to combine these two in my presentation. Can you suggest some topics in computer vision which are solved by optimization methods in graph theory (e.g. shortest-path, maximum flow, matching, etc.)? The newer the better.

Answer (score 1):

There was an enormous amount of work done in the late '90s and early 00's using graph-cut methods in Computer Vision. This is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_cuts_in_computer_vision